# Criar trigger no oracle

Tags: oracle, trigger

Tenho três tabelas: `Usuario`, `Lembrete` e `Lembrete_Usuario` no Oracle. Estou tentando criar uma trigger que quando eu inserir na tabela Usuario e na Lembrete, pegue os ids, de Usuario e Lembrete, e coloque na tabela Usuario_Lembrete.

Tabelas:

```
create table Usuario(
  idUsuario number(5),
  nome varchar2(20) not null,
  login varchar2(20) not null,
  senha varchar2(10) not null,
  email varchar2(50) not null,
  constraint idUsuario_pk primary key(idUsuario)    
);
create table Lembrete(
  idLembrete number(5),
  titulo varchar2(255),
  hora number(5,2),
  dataLemb date,
  repetir number(5),
  descricao varchar2(50),   
  constraint idLembrete_pk primary key(idLembrete)  
);

create table Lembrete_Usuario(
  idUsuario number(5),
  idLembrete number(5),
  log_usuario date,
  constraint idUsuarioLembrete_fk foreign key(idUsuario) references Usuario(idUsuario),
  constraint idLembreteUsuario_fk foreign key(idLembrete) references Lembrete(idLembrete)
);
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você realmente precisa das 3 tabelas? Da maneira como descreveu, utilizando um `trigger`, eu não vejo uma forma de fazer isso, pois como você vai saber qual id de usuário está relacionado com o id do lembrete?

Comment: Então essa tabela "Lembrete_Usuario" foi criada devido ao fato de ser muitos para muitos, entre Usuario e Lembrete.

Comment: Posso estar errado, mas creio que não seja possível fazer isso pela `trigger`, você vai precisar controlar pela aplicação.

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela a atenção!